# How to make colliders for a darts board in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I was wondering how to make a darts board in Unity?

Of course it doesn't make triangular objects, or non symmetrical boxes as far as I know, so I would make the board mesh in Blender or something like this.

But how would I be able to detect where a dart had hit the certain area? Until now I have only used box, sphere and capsule colliders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems have quite a few possible answers. But I'll take a quick stab at it. I think the key is probably to define the dart board mathematically (distance from center and angles of each area). Then use ContactPoint.point to figure out in area the dart hit as compared to the center of the bulls eye.

Unity docs for ContactPoint.point

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint-point.html

And here's a thread that may be useful to get the angles calculated right:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458992/angle-between-two-vectors-2d

There's a million options for how to organize the data. I'd probably set up a small class that just stores start distance, end distance, start angle, end angle, and point value. Build an array with all the possible target areas then loop through it until a match is found (or not) and add the score.